# C# Custom Class using INotifyPropertyChanged not notifying on Assignment

Tags: c#

I have a class that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.
If I create a new instance of the object, the PropertyChanged event gets set after I retrieve a value from it.

Example:

```
MyItem itm = new MyItem();  //MyItem.PropertyChanged == null
string test = itm.Value;    //MyItem.PropertyChanged != null
```

If I assign itm the value of another MyItem, the PropertyChanged event remains null.

Example:

```
itm = (MyItem)cboMyItemsCombobox.SelectedItem; // Properties for itm change to the values 
                                               // of the selected item, but PropertyChanged 
                                               // == null
```

I believe the problem lies partially in my custom constructor for the class, but I'm not entirely sure.

The goal is to have a variable to hold data for a record, called mnuitm, that is bound to 
3 textbox objects. When the text in a textbox changes, the change is made to the property in mnuitm. When the property in mnuitm is changed, the change is made in the textbox.
This works if I create a new MenuItem and assign the values individually, but does not work if I assign an already populated MenuItem to mnuitm.

Here is my actual code for (hopefully) more clearity on the issue.

```
public partial class frmMenuItems : Form
{
    private class MenuItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Int32 mid;
        private string txt;
        private string url;
        private string scp;

        public MenuItem() { }

        public MenuItem(Int32 id, string txt, string url, string scp)
        {
            ID = id;
            Text = txt;
            URL = url;
            Script = scp;
        }

        public Int32 ID
        {
            get
            {
                return mid;
            }
            set
            {
                if (mid != value)
                {
                    mid = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("ID");
                }
            }
        }

        public string Text {
            get
            {
                return txt;
            }
            set
            {
                if (txt != value)
                {
                    txt = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Text");
                }
            }
        }

        public string URL {
            get
            {
                return url;
            }
            set
            {
                if (url != value)
                {
                    url = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("URL");
                }
            }
        }

        public string Script {
            get
            {
                return scp;
            }
            set
            {
                if (scp != value)
                {
                    scp = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Script");
                }
            }
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            ID = 0;
            Text = "";
            URL = "";
            Script = "";
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Text;
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string inf)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(inf));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }


    private MenuItem mnuitm;
    private MySqlConnection sqlcon;

    public frmMenuItems()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mnuitm.Clear();
    }

    private void frmMenuItems_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constr = "server={0};uid={1};pwd={2};database={3};";
        DBItem dbi = CountyDataManager.CountyData.DBConnection;
        constr = string.Format(constr, [MyHost], [MyUsername], [MyPassword], [MyDatabase]);
        sqlcon = new MySqlConnection(constr);
        sqlcon.Open();

        mnuitm = new MenuItem();
        SetBindings();
        RefreshList();
    }

    private void SetBindings()
    {
        txtMenuText.DataBindings.Clear();
        txtURL.DataBindings.Clear();
        txtScript.DataBindings.Clear();

        txtMenuText.DataBindings.Add("Text", mnuitm, "Text");
        txtURL.DataBindings.Add("Text", mnuitm, "URL");
        txtScript.DataBindings.Add("Text", mnuitm, "Script");
    }

    private void RefreshList()
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT `menuid`,`menutext`,`url`,`script` FROM tblindexmenu ORDER BY `menutext`", sqlcon))
        {
            lstMenuItems.Items.Clear();
            using (MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    lstMenuItems.Items.Add(new MenuItem(Int32.Parse(rdr[0].ToString()), rdr[1].ToString(),rdr[2].ToString(),rdr[3].ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void frmMenuItems_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        sqlcon.Close();
    }

    private void lstMenuItems_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstMenuItems.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            mnuitm = (MenuItem)lstMenuItems.SelectedItem;
        }
    }
}
```

---

After receiving feedback, I made the following changes:

Added CopyFrom() to MenuItem

```
public void CopyFrom(MenuItem itm)
{
    this.ID = itm.ID;
     this.URL = itm.URL;
     this.Text = itm.Text;
     this.Script = itm.Script;
}
```

I then modified the SelectedIndexChanged code to use the new function

```
mnuitm.CopyFrom((MenuItem)lstMenuItems.SelectedItem);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. When you write

```
itm = (MyItem)cboMyItemsCombobox.SelectedItem;
```

you haven't changed any of the properties of the MenuItem `itm` used to point to, rather you changed the MenuItem `itm` points to.

One option for what you need is add a function to `MenuItem` that looks like

```
SetFromOtherMenuItem(MenuItem other)
{
    this.Url = other.Url
    //etc
}
```

Again, `PropertyChanged` means that a **property on some instance has changed**. In your case, only one of the variables pointing to that instance changed (to point to a different instance).

Comment: Thank you, this worked out great. Though it is what I was trying to avoid, but I can't win them all.

Comment: You're welcome. You could also stick with the assignment, and call a method, say, `NotifyallProperties` which will simply call NotifyPropertyChanged for all the properties